# java async service implementation using BlockingQueue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to write my own Async service implementation alongside my already existing Synchronous version.

I have the following so far:

```
@Service("asynchronousProcessor")
public class AsynchronousProcessor extends Processor {

   private BlockingQueue<Pair<String, MyRequest>> requestQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public AsynchronousProcessor(final PBRequestRepository pbRequestRepository,
                                     final JobRunner jobRunner) {
        super(pbRequestRepository, jobRunner);
    }

    @Override
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request, String id) {
        super.saveTheRequestInDB(request);
        // add task to blocking queue and have it processed in the background
    }

}
```

Basically I have an endpoint RestController class that calls `process()`. The async version should queue the request in a BlockingQueue and have it processed in the background.

I am unsure how to implement this code to solve this problem. Whether I should use `ExecutorService` and how best to fit with this current design.

It would be useful to have some controls such as before executing a task or after executing a task calls.

Any answer with some code samples to show design would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If the only requirement is to process it asynchronously then I'd strongly recommend consider using [spring inbuilt @Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) for this purpose. Using this approach however will not be interface compatible with your existing process method of Processor since the return type MUST be either void or wrapped in Future type. This limitation is for good reasons since the async execution can not return the response immediately thus Future wrapper is the only way to get access to result should that be needed.

Following solution outline lays out what should be done in order to switch from sync execution to async execution while retaining interface compatibility. All important points are mentioned with inline comments. Please note, although this is interface compatible, the return type is null (for the reasons stated above). If you MUST need the return value within your controller than this approach (or any async approach for that matter) is NOT going to work unless you switch to async controller as well (a different topic with much wider change and design though). Following outline also include pre and post execution hooks.

```
/**
 * Base interface extracted from existing Processor.
 * Use this interfae as injection type in the controller along 
 * with @Qualifier("synchProcessor") for using sync processor.
 * Once ready, switch the Qualifier to asynchronousProcessor
 * to start using async instead.
 */
public interface BaseProcessor {
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request, String id);
}

@Service("synchProcessor")
@Primary
public class Processor implements BaseProcessor {
    @Override
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request, String id) {
        // normal existing sync logic
    }
}

@Service("asynchronousProcessor")
public class AsynchronousProcessor implements BaseProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private AsynchQueue queue;
    
        
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request, String id) {
        queue.process(request,id);
        // async execution can not return result immediately
        // this is a hack to have this implementation interface 
        // compatible with existing BaseProcessor
        return null; 
    }
}

@Component
public class AsynchQueue {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("synchProcessor")
    private BaseProcessor processor;

    /**
     * This method will be scheduled by spring scheduler and executd 
     * asynchronously using an executor. Presented outline will
     * call preProcess and postProcess methods before actual method
     * execution. Actual method execution is delegated to existing
     * synchProcessor resuing it 100% AS-IS.
     */
    @Override
    @Async
    public void process(MyRequest request, String id) {
        preProcess(request, id);
        MyResponse response = processor.process(request, id);
        postProcess(request, id, response);
    }
    
    private void preProcess(MyRequest request, String id) {
        // add logic for pre processing here
    }
    
    private void postProcess(MyRequest request, String id, MyResponse response) {
        // add logic for post processing here
    }

}
```

Another use case could be to batch process the db updates instead of processing them using one by one as you are doing already. This is especially useful if you have high volume and db updates are becoming bottleneck. For this case, using a BlockingQueue makes sense. Following is the solution outline that you can use for this purpose. Again, although this is interface compatible, the return type is still null. You can further fine tune this outline to have multiple processing threads (or spring executor for that matter) should that be needed for batch processing. For one similar use case, a single processing thread with batch updates was sufficient for my needs, concurrent db updates were presenting bigger problems due to db level locks in concurrent execution.

```
public class MyRequestAndID {
    private MyRequest request;
    prviate String id;
    
    public MyRequestAndID(MyRequest request, String id){
        this.request = request;
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public MyRequest getMyRequest() {
        return this.request;
    }
    
    public String MyId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

@Service("asynchronousProcessor")
public class BatchProcessorQueue implements BaseProcessor{
    /* Batch processor which can process one OR more items using a single DB query */
    @Autowired
    private BatchProcessor batchProcessor;

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<MyRequestAndID> inQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private Set<MyRequestAndID> processingSet = new HashSet<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Thread processingThread = new Thread(() -> processQueue());
        processingThread.setName("BatchProcessor");
        processingThread.start();
    }
    
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request, String id) {
        enqueu(new MyRequestAndID(request, id));
        // async execution can not return result immediately
        // this is a hack to have this implementation interface 
        // compatible with existing BaseProcessor
        return null; 
    }

    public void enqueu(MyRequestAndID job) {
        inQueue.add(job);
    }

    private void processQueue() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                processQueueCycle();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ioex) {
            logger.error("Interrupted while processing queue", ioex);
        }
    }

    private void processQueueCycle() throws InterruptedException {
        // blocking call, wait for at least one item
        MyRequestAndID job = inQueue.take();
        processingSet.add(job);
        updateSetFromQueue();
        processSet();
    }

    private void processSet() {
        if (processingSet.size() < 1)
            return;
        int qSize = processingSet.size();
        preProcess(processingSet)
        batchProcessor.processAll(processingSet);
        postProcess(processingSet)
        processingSet.clear();
    }

    private void updateSetFromQueue() {
        List<MyRequestAndID> inData = Arrays.asList(inQueue.toArray(new MyRequestAndID[0]));
        if (inData.size() < 1)
            return;
        inQueue.removeAll(inData);
        processingSet.addAll(inData);
    }
    
    private void preProcess(Set<MyRequestAndID> currentSet) {
        // add logic for pre processing here
    }
    
    private void postProcess(Set<MyRequestAndID> currentSet) {
        // add logic for post processing here
    }
}
```